# Setting Anvil unit test framework in Titanium

Tags: unit-testing, titanium

Can anyone help me in setting up Anvil testing framework in Titanium Mobile project.
I gone through this git hub repo https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/tree/2_1_X/anvil/driver

my major concerns are:

1. How to setup anvil in my Titanium project.In the readMe file they only mentioned how to use driver and how it will drive the harness but there is no mention of how my Titanium mobile project will going to use anvil and run the test cases.
2. As harness is an app, and it contain all the test cases, suites in it. By going through the test suites I didn't found how those test suites are linked with the functions in my actual titanium mobile project.
   I have that knowledge that to run the test cases we initiate and start test suits in the app.js of harness, but how that test cases gonna serve to my titanium mobile project.